# User-rate limit exceeded returned for only one user in domain while others work fine

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, quota, google-api-nodejs-client, google-developers-console

I am using Gmail API to fetch messages to database.

Yesterday I was testing something and sent too many requests in a small period of time and I might have been blacklisted.

When I want to fetch mails from specific user I get error below. However if I run same script for any other user in domain, there would be no issues.

What bothers me the `Retry after DATE` in first line of the error just keeps increasing each time I try again.

Should I wait more or is there anything I can do to fix this?

I am using OAUTH JWT domain wide [delegation] authorization.

```
{ Error: User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2017-02-02T13:15:27.785Z
    at Request._callback (/var/www/apps/gmail-api/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:85:15)
    at Request.self.callback (/var/www/apps/gmail-api/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/www/apps/gmail-api/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/www/apps/gmail-api/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
  code: 429,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'usageLimits',
       reason: 'rateLimitExceeded',
       message: 'User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2017-02-02T13:15:27.785Z' } ] }
```

Please note that quotas are far from exceeded.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When testing gmail make sure that you are testing with a throw away
>   gmail account if you spam to much you can get shut down and you don't
>   want to shut down your developer account.

Depending up on which quota you hit sometimes changing users can get you around it. This is because some quotas are user / account based while others are project based. I have three or four accounts I use for testing so you send some requests with each keeps you from getting black listed.

Besides that you normally get blocked until `midnight West cost USA time`.   I haven't seen that they are reporting a time before must be something new.

Comment: Is this related to the domain wide delegated user or the specific user in domain I fetch mails from?

Comment: I haven't tested domains tbh but my personal guess would say it is the user  if you can recreate it you can test it to find out. I have done that before :)